# Phonon backend capabilities are too narrow

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, phonon

I created a UI using Qt Designer and am building the logic in pyqt4c. When trying to play either video or audio most formats are not being supported although I am fairly certain they should be.

This is the `Phonon.BackendCapabilities.availableMimeTypes()` output:

```
application/kate
application/ogg
application/x-3gp
application/x-ogg-avi
application/x-ogm-audio
application/x-ogm-video
audio/mpeg
audio/ogg
audio/webm
audio/x-alaw
audio/x-amr-nb-sh
audio/x-amr-wb-sh
audio/x-au
audio/x-dts
audio/x-flac
audio/x-m4a
audio/x-matroska
audio/x-mulaw
audio/x-private1-dts
audio/x-sbc
audio/x-speex
audio/x-vorbis
audio/x-vorbis+ogg
audio/x-wav
audio/x-wavpack
multipart/x-mixed-replace
video/mj2
video/ogg
video/quicktime
video/webm
video/x-dv
video/x-fli
video/x-flv
video/x-matroska
video/x-matroska-3d
video/x-msvideo
video/x-theora
video/x-vp8
video/x-vp9
```

I checked and in `/usr/share/mime`: I have a huge amount of codecs and I can play any video/audio format in any player: vlc, dragonplayer, mlv, mplayer, etc.

How can I expand my available codecs? Am I supposed to add any path to the phobos class?

Comment: Have you checked the current backend phonon is using? On my system I have 2 backends - VLC and GStreamer and VLC plays everything where GStreamer fails on particular formats.

Comment: @Iskren i did not check. I find the documentation hard to read. I tried my best to find which methods i can use and i am still struggling a bit. Are you saying i am able to switch backend dynamically and that each programmer has a different capability set?

Answer (score 1):

The currently running phonon backend is responsible for format support. You can switch to a different one to get additional MimeTypes / formats supported.

Read below for a more comprehensive explanation.

Example program:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
from PyQt4.phonon import Phonon
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

print len(Phonon.BackendCapabilities.availableMimeTypes())
```

In KDE `System settings -> Multimedia -> Audio and Video Settings -> Backend` I have selected "VLC". Running the above produces `89`. Going back to the Backend configuration, selecting "GStreamer" and running the script again outputs `213`. This means the GStreamer backend supports more MimeTypes than the VLC one. Unfortunately, Phonon's backend is system-wide and you can't override it for a single application, or at least I couldn't find out how by looking at the Phonon class.

Comment: I solved and posted solution. Thanks for the feedback though! =)

Answer (score 0):

---------------------------- MY SOLUTION---------------------------------

Since Phonon takes advantage of your system capabilities it is up to you to install libraries to encode and decode media. However, what i did not realize was the necessity to install phonon-qt4 compatible libraries. So:

Using qt4 install:

phonon-qt4-vlc

phonon-qt4-mplayer (unmanaged so possibly out-dated)

Using qt5:

phonon-qt5-vlc
(etc)

If anyone has a similar issue and this does not work feel free to post here!